# Returning AJAX Success and Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have built a login script that uses AJAX to submit form data.

The PHP part works fine without AJAX. But the system doesnt work with AJAX Implementation.

It always Displays the below message even though the PHP file returns **true**[correct username & password] ... Seems like the **if** condition in Jquery is not working.

> Incorrect Username/Password

HTML Result Div

```
<div id="user-result" align="center"></div>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var form = $('#loginform');
        form.submit(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                cache: false,
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "true") {
                        $("#user-result").html("<font color ='#006600'> Logged in | Redirecting..</font>").show("fast");
                        setTimeout(
                            function () {
                                window.location.replace("index.php");
                            }, 1500);
                    } else {
                        $("#user-result").html("<font color ='red'> Incorrect Username/Password</font>").show("fast");
                    }

                }

            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

fn_login.php

```
<?php
{
    session_start();
    include_once 'db_connect.php';

    if (isset($_POST))
     {
        $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $logpwd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM manager WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);


        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($password);
        $stmt->fetch();


        // Check if a user has provided the correct password by comparing what they typed with our hash
        if (password_verify($logpwd, $password))
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * from manager WHERE email LIKE '{$email}' LIMIT 1";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $id = $row['id'];
            $conn->query("UPDATE manager SET lastlogin = NOW() WHERE id = $id");

            $_SESSION['manager_check'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['fullname'] = $row['fullname'];
            $_SESSION['designation'] = $row['designation'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            echo "true";
        }
         else {
            die();
        }
     }
}

?>
```

Can someone please point out the mistake in the code/practice.

```
EDIT
```

Just Tried disabling AJAX, the PHP file works correctly echoing `true` when username/pass is correct

Comment: Try `if( $.trim(data) == "true")` insted of `if(data == "true")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spaces after `?>`

So, the AJAX response is having spaces after `true`.

**Solution:**

Remove `?>` from the end of PHP file.

It will not affect any PHP functionality.

And you AJAX response will be without spaces.

Excluding closing tag `?>` from the end of PHP file is standard practice for modern PHP frameworks and CMSs.

**Tips for debugging AJAX:**

1) Always use Firefox (with Firebug Add) on Or Chrome.

2) Use `Console` tab of Firebug, to check which AJAX requests are going.

3) Here, you can see input parameters, headers and most important response.

4) So, in short you can debug a whole AJAX request life cycle.

Comment: Add this line in success function: console.log(data); And post output here.

Comment: added and executed. where can i find the output?

Comment: If firefox, turn on Firebug. Here you get 'Console' tab. Check here.

Comment: Chrome also has console. Right click on any element and choose inspect option.

Comment: yes there was a php include which was echoing a comment before true... 

Solved... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can echo `json_encode(array('success'=>true))` from php code and modify your `if` condition in jquery with `if(data.success){}` Your modified code becomes

```
<?php
{
    session_start();
    include_once 'db_connect.php';

    if (isset($_POST))
     {
        $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $logpwd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM manager WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);


        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($password);
        $stmt->fetch();


        // Check if a user has provided the correct password by comparing what they typed with our hash
        if (password_verify($logpwd, $password))
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * from manager WHERE email LIKE '{$email}' LIMIT 1";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $id = $row['id'];
            $conn->query("UPDATE manager SET lastlogin = NOW() WHERE id = $id");

            $_SESSION['manager_check'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['fullname'] = $row['fullname'];
            $_SESSION['designation'] = $row['designation'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
        }
         else {
            die();
        }
     }
}
```

AND JQuery becomes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var form = $('#loginform');
        form.submit(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                cache: false,
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        $("#user-result").html("<font color ='#006600'> Logged in | Redirecting..</font>").show("fast");
                        setTimeout(
                            function () {
                                window.location.replace("index.php");
                            }, 1500);
                    } else {
                        $("#user-result").html("<font color ='red'> Incorrect Username/Password</font>").show("fast");
                    }

                }

            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: tried it.. the same result...

Also replaced current condition with 
if(data.success){}

Comment: it was a comment from another php include which was messing with the return value.. problem solved..